# Php if statement redirection

Tags: php

I have a simple php page that contain form with action that directed to a file called `getData.php`, here’s the PHP page:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['login_attempt'])) {
    echo 'LOGIN ATTEMP 1';
}else{
    echo 'NO LOGIN ATTEMP';
}
?>
<form id="info" action="getData.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="input" name="info1" /><br>
    <input type="password" class="input" name="info2" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="" id="submit-button">
</form>
```

And here's the `getData.php` file:

```
if (!isset($_GET['login_attempt'])) {
    header('location: /login.php?login_attempt=1');
} else {
    header('location: http://www.stackoverflow.com');
}
```

As you can see in the `getData.php` file after two attempts of logging in the php page should go to `http://www.stackoverflow.com`, but the php page get stuck in `/login.php?login_attempt=1` forever after the first attempt, why?

Comment: Why should it go to stackoverflow.com?

Comment: I want it to go to stackoverflow.com after the second attempt, so the page should do that:
As I open the page I get "NO LOGIN ATTEMPT"
After submitting the form "LOGIN ATTEMPT 1"
After submitting the form again it should now go to stackoverflow.com

Comment: try `if (isset($_GET['login_attempt']))` whithout the exclamation...but you never set `login_attempt` and you'r using post instead get method...better make a tutorial

Comment: Because your form method is post, and you are checking `$_GET` - so `$_GET['login_attempt']` will never be set.

Comment: @Jon is right, `$_GET`-array is never assigned when you submit your form

Comment: if I try `if (isset($_GET['login_attempt']))`whithout the exclamation it will directly go to "stackoverflow.com" without giving a login attempt:/

Comment: if you never set `login attempt` what is the case?

Comment: and how are you checking the attempts? 2 options: is missing code or you dont know what you'r doing

Comment: **Note:** Always `exit` or `die` after setting location header.

Comment: @leri that depends on what you want to do

Comment: The page should do that:<br>
1. On opening the page it should give me "NO LOGIN ATTEMPT"<br>
2. After submitting the code it should give me "LOGIN ATTEMPT 1"<br>
3. After submitting the code again it should go to "stackoverflow.com"

Comment: @EmilioGort Tell me scenario when you want to execute script after sending `location` header.

Comment: @Leri run some script like a log

Comment: @EmilioGort Logging could effectively happen before redirection. I would not want to maintain code that is out of usual flow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can handle this

```
<?php
$attempt    =   1;
if(isset($_GET['login_attempt'])) {
    $attempt    ++;//Now attempt will have 2
    echo 'LOGIN ATTEMP 1';
}else{
    echo 'NO LOGIN ATTEMP';
}
?>
<form id="info" action="getData.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" class="input" name="login_attempt" value='<?php echo $attempt;?>' /><br>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="info1" /><br>
    <input type="password" class="input" name="info2" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="" id="submit-button">
</form>
```

And here's the "getData.php" file:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login_attempt']) AND $_POST['login_attempt'] !== 2) {
    header('location: /login.php?login_attempt=1');
} else {
    header('location:http://www.stackoverflow.com');
}
?>
```

EDIT

Why your page stuck on first attempt. Here is the answer.

When ever you redirect to login page the first condition is matched. As you have no criteria to tell `getData.php` which attempt is this there fore you are stuck. Use a variable `$attempt` as i have used in login.php initialize it with 1. If there is 2nd attempt increment it with 1. Put it in h hidden field so that `getData.php` its number. and will then redirect to according to your needs.

Comment: Its his problem. Here we are giving the process

Comment: -1 More likely this will trigger _headers already sent_ warning.

Comment: i dont think so. We are not printing anything in getData.php

Comment: @raheelshan Never mind, you have not formatted code so I thought it was one script. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
<input type="submit" value="" id="submit-button">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="" id="submit-button" name="login_attempt">
```

and

from file `getData.php`

change the line

```
if (!isset($_GET['login_attempt']))
```

to

```
if (!isset($_POST['login_attempt']))
```

as you are using post method in the form ( `<form id="info" action="getData.php" method="post">`).

and change this line to

```
if(isset($_GET['login_attempt']))
```

to

```
if($_GET['login_attempt']==1)
```

i think this will solve your problem.

Comment: it directly goes to stackoverflow.com, it should give a login attempt and then go to stackoverflow.com

Comment: @System32 I added one more change the answer check it out.